# Why is the result epoch different than the beginning in this case?

Tags: python

Attempt at making an Epoch to Date converter manually.  I have used the exact conversions but the result Epoch is still a month past the input date.  Input Date is `2003-08-30 11:51:00`  but this block gives me `2003-07-28 11:51:00`

```py
import datetime
epoch_value = 1062244260
year = epoch_value / 86400 / 365.24 + 1970
days = (year - int(year)) * 365.24
months = days / 30.44
a = (months - int(months)) * 30.44
b = (a - int(a)) * 24
c = (b - int(b)) * 60
d = (c - int(c)) * 60
print(datetime.datetime(int(year), int(months), int(a), int(b), int(c), int(d)))
print((datetime.datetime(int(year), int(months), int(a), int(b), int(c), int(d))).timestamp())
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why do you need to manually calculate this. Although there is a [datetime.fromtimestamp()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp) method which you can make use of.

```
import datetime

epoch_value = 1062244260
print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(epoch_value, datetime.timezone.utc))
```

Output:

```
2003-08-30 11:51:00+00:00
```